# how to centre Bootstrap drop down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After clicking the menu the drop down is aligned to the left.
How do you get the drop down menu to align to the centre of the screen?

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div align="center" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul float: right class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Those</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following css

```
    .dropdown-menu{
           margin-left:calc(50% - 80px);
           margin-right:calc(50% - 80px);}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/n6s5gky9/)

Answer (score 0):

**Jarvis** Hi there.

Try this... Just add the Bootstrap **class** `text-center`.

To this line in you navbar code block.

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

This will place the list text in the middle.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14o2tf3h/)**.

[image: center list menu items Bootstrap]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it!